# A question on invariant measures

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X, \mathcal{B}, T)$  be a topological dynamical system and $M(X, T)$ be the set of all invariant measures.

I do not know is there some nice functional characterization of  the following set
$\{f\in C(X): \text{the set}\{\int fd\mu: \mu \in M(X,T)\}\text{is a singleton} \}$.

Any comments and remarks will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your set consists exactly of weak coboundaries plus constants.

A function $f\in C(X)$ is called a *coboundary* if $f = h \circ T - h$ for some $h\in C(X)$. A function is called a *weak coboundary* if it is a uniform limit of coboundaries.

> **Proposition A.** $f \in C(X)$ is a weak coboundary if and only if $\int f d\mu=0$ for every $\mu \in M(X,T)$.

*Proof.* The "only if" part is trivial, so let's prove the "if" part. Assume $\int f d\mu=0$ for every $\mu \in M(X,T)$. Denote by $f^{(n)} := f + f\circ T + \dots +f\circ T^{n-1}$ the $n$-th Birkhoff sum of $f$. As explained in RW's answer, the sequence of Cesàro averages $\frac{1}{n}f^{(n)}$ converges uniformly to $0$. So the proposition will be a consequence of the following lemma:

> **Lemma B.** For every $f \in C(X)$ and every $n$, the function $\frac{1}{n}f^{(n)} - f$ is a coboundary.

It's an entertaining exercise to prove the lemma; but if you're in a hurry, here's the solution.

*Proof.* Let $h := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f^{(i)}$ (where $f^{(0)}:=0$). Then
$$
h \circ T - h = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f^{(i)}\circ T-f^{(i)}\right) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(f \circ T^i - f\right)=\frac{f^{(n)}}{n} - f.
$$

*Remarks:* The terminology *weak coboundary* comes from [the 2002 Inventiones paper by Bousch and Jenkinson](http://topo.math.u-psud.fr/~bousch/preprints/pos.pdf). See their paper for an explicit example of a weak coboundary that is not a coboundary. I think that Proposition A and Lemma B above are kind of folklore. Proposition A is Lemma 3 from Bousch-Jenkinson; for a more complete statement (and a proof using Hahn-Banach), see Proposition 2.13 in [Katok-Robinson's survey](http://www.math.psu.edu/katok_a/pub/KR.pdf). Lemma B is used as obvious in Bousch-Jenkinson; I learned it from Andrés Navas. [We](http://www.mat.uc.cl/~jairo.bochi/docs/Bochi_Navas_ETDS.pdf) have used these ideas in non-commutative settings.

Answer (score 5):

I presume that the state space $X$ is compact. Then your set is precisely the set of functions $f\in C(X)$, for which the Cesaro averages 
$$
C_n f(x) = \frac1{n+1} \Bigl( f(x) + f(Tx) + \dots + f(T^n x) \Bigr)
$$
uniformly converge to a constant.

This is, obviously, a generalization of a characterization of uniquely ergodic systems as those for which **all** Cesaro averages uniformly converge to constants, see [Uniform convergence of Birkhoff averages and unique ergodicity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152132/uniform-convergence-of-birkhoff-averages-and-unique-ergodicity), and the proof is more or less the same.

The idea is to use the ``Krylov-Bogolyubov'' measures
$$
\kappa_{x,n} = \frac1{n+1} \Bigl(\delta_x + \delta_{Tx} + \dots + \delta_{T^n x} \Bigr)
$$

Indeed, if $C_n f$ does not converge uniformly to a constant function, then there are sequences of points $x_k,y_k\in X$ and of integers $m_k,n_k$ such that $\kappa_{x_k,m_k}$ (resp., $\kappa_{y_k,n_k}$) weakly converges to a $T$-invariant measure $\mu$ (resp., $\nu$) with $\langle f,\mu \rangle \neq \langle f,\nu \rangle$. Conversely, if $\langle f,\mu \rangle \neq \langle f,\nu \rangle$ then by Birkhoff's ergodic theorem $C_n f$ can not uniformly converge to a constant.

Answer (score 2):

As in RW's answer, I assume $X$ is compact, and $C(X)$ means continuous real-valued functions (the extension to complex continuous functions is routine). But now assume something much stronger: $X$ is zero-dimensional.

Then, modulo coboundaries (functions of the form $f - T\circ f$), and assuming  something like recurrence (or some condition known to guarantee an obvious pre-ordering is a valid partial ordering, see below), these are just the functions that are infinitesimals plus a constant function; simply note that $f- \int f\,d\mu$ (for these special $f$s) vanishes at all the measures (or more accurately, vanishes at all the positive linear functionals on $C(X)$ that are induced by the invariant measures). This describes precisely what are known as the infinitesimal subgroup of the (pre-) ordered group $C(X)/(\text{image}(I-T))$. [See towards the end of

M Michael Boyle and David E Handelman
*Orbit equivalence, flow equivalence and ordered cohomology*
Israel Journal of Mathematics
December 1996, Volume 95, Issue 1, pp 169-210.]

Most of this deals with integer-valued continuous functions---which of course are interesting only for highly disconnected spaces; but at one point we consider real-valued functions. Somewhat later, it was shown by Nick Ormes that the ordered group (here a vector space) is generically laced with infinitesimals.]

Without something like recurrence, the pre-ordering is not likely to be a proper partial ordering, and in that case the answer still consists of the infinitesimals, but with a slightly different interpretation.