# Does ergodic theorem apply to trajectories outside of attractor?

Tags: measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Ergodic theorem says that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^nf(T^tx) = \displaystyle\int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu$ for $\mu$-almost every $x$. In many cases, the support of $\mu$ has zero Lebesgue measure.

My question is that, what if $f$ is uniformly continuous on a neighborhood of the trajectory, and $x$ is outside of the support of $\mu$? When can we have similar identities? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Axiom A diffeomorphisms have this property. The following result is due to Bowen and Ruelle.

**Theorem**
*Let $X$ be a connected compact manifold and $T : X \rightarrow X$ be an Axiom A $C^2$ diffeomorphism: the non wandering set $\Omega$ of $T$ is an hyperbolic set and the periodic orbits of $T$ are dense in $\Omega$. Then there is a finite number of disjoint compact attractors $K_i$ included in $\Omega$, each of them supporting an ergodic probability measure $\mu_i$ called a Sinai-Ruelle-Bowen measure, such that the union of the bassins of attraction $B(K_i) = \{x\in X \mid d(T^n(x, K_i)\rightarrow 0\}$ is of full Lebesgue measure.*

*Moreover, for lebesgue almost $x\in B(K_i)$, for all $f : X\rightarrow \bf R$ uniformly continuous,
$$
{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n f \circ T^k(x) \rightarrow \int f d\mu_i.
$$*

The set of Axiom A flows is open in the $C^2$ topology but is far from dense in the set of all $C^2$ diffeomorphisms on $X$ in general. There are  extensions to non-uniformly hyperbolic systems of that result but also many counterexamples.

The theorem follows from the fact that a point in the bassin of $K_i$ is on the stable leaf of a point on $K_i$ so that the two Birkhoff means are asymptotic. As a result, the asymptotic behavior of the trajectories of a set of positive measure of points is dictated by the measure $\mu_i$ on the attractor, even if that measure is singular with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Is there any theory giving a definite answer, i.e.  the identity holds for every x, instead of for almost every x?

Comment: If $x$ is a periodic point of $T$, the mean alors its orbit converges to the integral with respect to the Dirac measure along the orbit, not to the integral  with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Convergence for all x is related to unique ergodicity, not ergodicity.

Comment: Can we claim that the system is uniquely ergodic if the maximal attractor can be approximated by a single trajectory?

Comment: If the Birkhoff means converge for all x, then the system is uniquely ergodic. See e.g. the book of Walters, ergodic theory.

Comment: Yes that is a direct result by the definition of unique ergodicity. But this statement does not help me because what I want to know is when the BIrkhoff converge for all x... So I need to know when a system is uniquely ergodic in a straightforward/intuitive way... Can we say that the system is uniquely ergodic if the maximal attractor can be approximated by a single trajectory?

Comment: I see what you meant. I just checked other questions on this website and someone posted a question about what you just mentioned. But I guess there are some result that is more straightforward? For instance, is Lorenz 63 system uniquely ergodic? How do we prove it?

Comment: Sorry for being ambiguous. I meant that the maximal attractor is included in the closure of a single orbit. The following thread mentioned that if BIrkhoff converges for all x and if one orbit is dense in X, then it is uniquely ergodic. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152132/uniform-convergence-of-birkhoff-averages-and-unique-ergodicity

Comment: The Lorenz system is of course not uniquely ergodic. As mentioned above, a system with several periodic orbits can't be uniquely ergodic since each periodic orbits gives rise to an invariant probability measure. The systems I speak about in my answer are not uniquely ergodic either. Hyperbolic systems have a set of periodic points dense in the recurrent set by the closing lemma. See e.g. the book by Katok and Hasselblatt.

Comment: My last reply was not correct so I deleted it. Now I have a new question... Thank you in advance for your patience. In Lorenz 63, as long as x is not on the periodic orbits, the Birkhoff  should converge.  If x is on the periodic orbits, then of course it converges too. This is what I am really curious about. In Lorenz 63, how do you prove that Birkhoff converges for every x?

Comment: If you have a new question... you should post it as a new question. Also it is not true that the Birkhoff averages converges for all x non periodic to the equilibrium measure. In fact, for these kind of systems, the set of points for which the Birkhoff means do not converge is a dense $G_\delta$ set. Also the number of invariant probability measures is not countable.

Comment: Do you mean even for Lorenz system, the Birkhoff  means do not converge for all x? Can you suggest some reference on that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, for the Lorenz attractor, and in fact  more generally for hyperbolic systems,  there is an uniformly continuous function $f$ such that the set of points for which the Birkhoff means do not converge is uncountable. In fact this follows from the same result for expanding maps of the interval, since the Lorenz attractor has such section. You should first understand what is going on on simpler systems such as $x \rightarrow 2x$ mod $1$ since this is the same phenomenon.

Comment: Can you suggest a reference book? Does Katok and Hasselblatt discuss about this? Thank you.

Comment: I see how the interval expansion system works. And do you mean Lorenz is the same as the interval expansion because that the first Lyapunov exponent of Lorenz is positive? Then actually even for points on the Lorenz attractor, the Birkhoff means may not converge?

Comment: I suggest reading the original paper by Lorenz(https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/atsc/20/2/1520-0469_1963_020_0130_dnf_2_0_co_2.xml). The interval map is depicted in Fig.4 and everything is pretty well explained. It is true that for an uncountable set of points on the attractor, the Birkhoff means do not converge for a well chosen function (arguably it converges  for all points if the function is 0!).

Comment: Fig4 is interesting... I did not know that there is a deterministic relation between the current maximum of Z and the following maximum of Z. Thank you very much.

Comment: If we require f to be differentiable, does there still exist some point on the attractor of Lorenz system so that the Birkhoff mean does not converge?

Comment: I figured it out... My construction for the uniformly continuous case was wrong. So I asked the stupid question...

Answer (score 2):

The key word you are looking for is "physical measures", sometimes known as SRB measures (because of the result.that coudy mentions).

See https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1019762724717

A related notion you may find interesting is given here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4074

A nice paper discussing related notions is the following https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01212280